# BASH - Only printing the deepest directory in path

Tags: linux, bash, tree

I need some help.....

In my .bashrc file I have a VERY useful function (It may be a bit rough and ready, and a bit hacky, but it works a treat!) that reads an input file, and uses the 'tree' function on each of the input lines to create a directory tree. this tree is then printed into an output file (along with the size of the folder).

```
multitree()
{
    while read cheese
    do
        pushd . > /dev/null
        pushd $cheese > /dev/null
        echo -e "$cheese \n\n" >> ~/Desktop/$2.txt
        tree -idf . >> ~/Desktop/$2.txt
        echo -e "\n\n\n" >> ~/Desktop/$2.txt
        du -sh --si >> ~/Desktop/$2.txt
        echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" >> ~/Desktop/$2.txt
        popd > /dev/null
    done < $1
        cat ~/done
}
```

This is a time saver like no end, and outputs a snippet like the following:

```
./foo
./foo/bar
./foo/bar/1
./foo/bar/1/2
```

etc etc....

however, the first (and most tedious) thing I need to do is remove all entries leaving only the deepest folder path (Using the above example it would be reduced to just ./foo/bar/1/2)

Is there a way of processing the file before/after the tree function to only print the deepest levels?

I know something like python might do a better job, but my issue is I've never used python And I'm not sure the work systems would let me run python... they let us modify our own .bashrc so I'm not too worried!

Thanks in advance guys!!!!

Owen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use

```
find . -type d -links 2
```

Replace `.` with a directory if desired.

EDIT: Explanation:

`find` searches a directory for files that match a given filter. In this case, the directory is `.`, and the filter is `-type d -links 2`.

`-type d` filters for directories

`-links 2` filters for those that have two (hard) links to their name. Effectively, this filters for all directories that have no subdirectories, because only those have two: The one in their parent directory and the `.` link in themselves. Those with subdirectories also have the `..` links in their subdirectories.

Comment: You might have to explain that one to me....... i looked at the Find man page, but it didnt help me understand what you mean...

Comment: I edited in a bit. There's not really a lot to explain, though.

Comment: `find . -links 2` will not suffice. Try it after `touch ./abcd; ln ./abcd ./pqrs` Note: `ln`, not `ln -s`... But +1 for this info :-)

Comment: Cheers that makes more sense! what is the relevance of the '2' on the -links? it seems to work a treat though!

Comment: Oh, turns out I misunderstood how exactly it works, which is a bit embarrassing, but I learned something new today, so that's good. I fixed the explanation accordingly.

Comment: Basically this is the same answer as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203991/38701 and won't work e.g. on MacOS

Comment: @WolfgangFahl According to https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html this approach is POSIX-compliant. I don't have a MacOS X on which to test it, but I can confirm that it works on FreeBSD, and as far as I'm aware MacOS X uses the same userland. As for the duplication, I find it a little annoying that you felt the need to comment on an answer from 2014 to point out that the same answer was given by someone else in 2015. No big deal, but...why?

Comment: Since the approach with bash didn't work in my environment I ended up not using a bash solution at all. See https://github.com/rc-dukes/dukes/blob/master/scripts/subdirs.py

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

You just need to count the number of "/" characters in each line.

If the current line has fewer than the number of "/" characters in the preceding line, the preceding line would be the "deepest" directory in its part of the hierarchy.

This line, and any subsequent line with still fewer "/" characters would NOT be the deepest directory in its part of the entire directory hierarchy. As soon as you get a line with the same number of "/" characters, or greater, then you can "reset" and, once again, keep an eye out for the first line with the fewer number of "/" characters.

And, finally, you need to handle the trivial case: only one line in your tree output, the current directory has no subdirectories, so it wins by default.

Another way you can implement this is by considering the following statement:

If a directory's name also exists as an exact prefix of another directory in the list, followed by the "/" character, then it is NOT the deepest directory in its part of the hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, thanks! but how would that work with multiple sub-directories? i would want the deepest level for each subdirectory.... starting to believe its not possible....

Comment: Given the following list of directories: ./one, ./one/subdir, ./two, ./two/subdir, can you explain why you believe that either of my two suggestions will not identify the two subdirs, correctly?